# Sending Mail in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

So I am running into an interesting error I have never seen before. I am trying to set up mail in development so that I can send actual emails to my self. So lets go through how I have set up mail

I have an initializer called `setup_mail.rb`

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smptp.gmail.com',
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :user_name =>  Figaro.env.EMAIL,
  :password =>  Figaro.env.PASSWORD,
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] =  Figaro.env.HOST
```

From there we have a mailer class in the mailers directory called `user_mailer.rb`

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "AisisPlatForm@AisisPlanner.com"

  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => "#{user.first_name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => 'Welcome to AisisPlatform!')
  end

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => "#{user.first_name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => 'Password Reset (AisisPlatform)')
  end
end
```

It has its appropriate views for both HTML and non HTML versions of said mail. We then do:

```
UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
```

in the user `create` controller to send the mail, but upon submitting the form and creating the user I instantly get:

```
SocketError (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

So I thought, lets look at the logs (Warning its very long):

```
UserMailer#registration_confirmation: processed outbound mail in 520.0ms

Sent mail to trolololololololo@mmmmmm.com (89.3ms)
Date: Fri, 04 Jul 2014 19:36:17 -0600
From: AisisPlatForm@AisisPlanner.com
To: trolololololololo <trolololololololo@mmmmmm.com>
Message-ID: <53b7569190dcc_957f3fc5b1ce122c939c1@Adams-Mac-mini.local.mail>
Subject: Welcome to AisisPlatform!
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_53b756918f0f4_957f3fc5b1ce122c93864";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_53b756918f0f4_957f3fc5b1ce122c93864
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

trolololololololo,

Welcome and thank you for signing up to AisisPlatform.

We believe that our small, simple and yet very powerful API will allow you to create blog you have always wanted to create.
We are constently growing and evolving the feature set and coming out with new ideas and concepts we hope to share with you.

We are more then grateful for your participation in our services and hope we can be of use to you in any way shape or form that will
help make you happy and excited to use and share our services and products.<

sincerly,

AisisPlatform

----==_mimepart_53b756918f0f4_957f3fc5b1ce122c93864
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h3>trolololololololo,</h3>

<p>Welcome and thank you for signing up to AisisPlatform.</p>

<p>We believe that our small, simple and yet very powerful API will allow you to create blog you have always wanted to create.
We are constently growing and evolving the feature set and coming out with new ideas and concepts we hope to share with you.</p>

<p>We are more then grateful for your participation in our services and hope we can be of use to you in any way shape or form that will
help make you happy and excited to use and share our services and products.</p>

<p>sincerly,</p>

<p><em>AisisPlatform</em></p>

----==_mimepart_53b756918f0f4_957f3fc5b1ce122c93864--

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1048ms

SocketError (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known):
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `initialize'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `open'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `tcp_socket'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:551:in `block in do_start'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `call'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `do_start'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
  mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
  mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'
  mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'
  actionmailer (4.1.0) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:527:in `block in deliver_mail'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionmailer (4.1.0) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:525:in `deliver_mail'
  mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `deliver'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bundler/gems/Xaaron-2ee49cf0018e/app/controllers/xaaron/users_controller.rb:20:in `create'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bundler/gems/promiscuous-9bda9a49ac13/gemfiles/lib/promiscuous/railtie.rb:6:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/Adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/Adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.5ms)
  [1m[36mPromiscuous Recovery Delete (23.8ms)[0m  [1mDELETE FROM _promiscuous WHERE id = 17[0m
  Rendered /Users/Adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/Adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/Adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (15.3ms)
```

What is going on? Why am I getting this error? I followed [Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email-revised?view=asciicast) Setting up mail. Is it out of date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you that Ruby is not able to find a DNS entry for the SMTP server.

This is because you have a typo in your configuration, its `smtp.gmail.com` and not `smptp.gmail.com`. Furthermore the `domain` should be your domain, not `gmail.com`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'aisisplanner.com',
  :user_name            => Figaro.env.EMAIL,
  :password             => Figaro.env.PASSWORD,
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail

Comment: Thats seriously the way its like "fake email?" is there no way to catch that and be like "sure we'll send it there ..... good luck getting it"

Comment: So this didn't work because when I viewed what e.message was even with my own personal email I got this: `"getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known"`